# How to get the $user object when authenticated with JWT on Laravel/Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

I have an application that does authentication with JWT. It is my first time creating one. When I try to get the user object in a function, I can't find a way to do it. Here is my code:

```
public function getEmail(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();

    return new JsonResponse(['message' => $user->email]);
}
```

It returns that the $user object is null, probably because the Auth class is related to session authentication. I am using this boilerplate: https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt

I have looked into the code but can't find a way to get the user, can somebody help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for it for hours, I found a working answer:

```
$user = app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this function?

JWTAuth::user();

Comment: It gives: Method [user] does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Guide for setting up with Lumen](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1102)

You can get it from request object :

**Example routes:**

```
$app->get('/login', function (Request $request) {
    $token = app('auth')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
});

$app->get('/me', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: Gives: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $request->user(); returns nothing..
when I then try to access $user, it is a non-object

Comment: \Auth::user(); also returns nothing